# How to access DbContext from outside of the Controller?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have class UserFactory where I want to check if User already exist in database, if not it will be automatically created. But having difficulties with accessing DbContext from outside the Controller.

```
    public UserFactory(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        _dbContext = new PMSContext(builder.Options) ;
    }

    public User Create(WindowsIdentity currentWindowsUser)
    {
        User user = new User();
        string name = currentWindowsUser.Name.Replace("DOMAIN\\", "");

        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal ADuser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, name);

        if(ADuser != null)
        {
            User userInDatabase = _dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.SamAccountName == name).FirstOrDefault();
        }
   }
```

And than in the Startup.cs I habe :

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PMSContext>()
        .UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]);
        User user = new UserFactory(builder).Create(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
    }
```

But I'm getting error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder' to 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContextOptionsBuilder'

Is this the right way to access DbContext from the outside of the Controller?

Comment: It could be that you are referencing 2 different EF dlls (i.e. the one with .Net Framework and the one with the new EF).

Comment: It does look like a reference error :/

Comment: Both classes use Microsoft.Data.Entity

Comment: Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder|
Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContextOptionsBuilder

you are referencing 2 different DbContextOptionsBuilder.

Comment: I get that, but how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]);
var context = new PMSContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

User user = new UserFactory(context).Create(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
```